# Show LoggedIn username on successful login [getting JSX and Router related error in code] --

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, mern

My aim is to show logged in user name and a logout link in the header section.
User logs in to my app. with username and password. Upon successful login,
I would like to show the respective username in the top right header strip, along with a logout link.

header strip html [located in App.js] -

```
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-custom">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="https://www.sellcodes.com/pro_indigo" target="_blank">
                    <img src={logoMain} width="30" height="30" alt="" />
                </a>
                <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">Football Legends</Link>
                <div className="collpase nav-collapse">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li className="navbar-item">
                            <Link to="/" className="nav-link">Players</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="navbar-item">
                            <Link to="/create" className="nav-link">Create Player</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="navbar-item">
                            <Link to="/hallofFamers" className="nav-link">Hall of Fame</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="navbar-item" style={{marginLeft:680}}>
                            <Link to="/login" className="nav-link">Login</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="navbar-item" style={{ marginLeft: 12 }}>
                            <Link to="/register" className="nav-link">Sign Up</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>


                </div>
            </nav>
```

login.js code -

```
import { login } from './shared/UserFunction';

onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        const user = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        }

        login(user).then(res => {
            this.props.history.push(`user/dashboard`)
        })

    }
```

As you can understand I have a separate file where my login implementation logic is written and I have just imported from there.

UserFunction.js code -

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { Router, Route, Link, RouteHandler } from 'react-router';

export const login = user => {
    return axios
        .post('http://localhost:4000/users/login', {
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password
        })
        .then(response => {
            localStorage.setItem('usertoken', (response.data));
            console.log('Login Successful');
            return response.data
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}

export const findToken = () => {
    return localStorage.getItem('usertoken');
}

export const logout =()=>
{
    localStorage.removeItem('usertoken');
    this.props.history.push('/login');
}
```

What I how I tried to do this is by following much the same approach in Angular *ngIf and templates.
So I tried following code -

```
import { findToken } from './components/shared/UserFunction';

<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-custom">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="https://www.sellcodes.com/pro_indigo" target="_blank">
                    <img src={logoMain} width="30" height="30" alt="" />
                </a>
                <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">Football Legends</Link>
                <div className="collpase nav-collapse">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li className="navbar-item">
                            <Link to="/" className="nav-link">Players</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="navbar-item">
                            <Link to="/create" className="nav-link">Create Player</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="navbar-item">
                            <Link to="/hallofFamers" className="nav-link">Hall of Fame</Link>
                        </li>
                        {findToken &&
                            [
                                <li className="navbar-item" style={{marginLeft:680}}>
                                    <Link to="/user/profile" className="nav-link">{the username supposed to be here}</Link>
                                </li>
                                <li className="navbar-item" style={{ marginLeft: 12 }}>
                                    <Link to="/login" className="nav-link">Logout</Link>
                                </li>
                            ]
                        }
                        <li className="navbar-item" style={{marginLeft:680}}>
                            <Link to="/login" className="nav-link">Login</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="navbar-item" style={{ marginLeft: 12 }}>
                            <Link to="/register" className="nav-link">Sign Up</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>


                </div>
            </nav>
```

But this is giving me a host of errors related to JSX and Parent Element Router. 
So how should I approach this? A better way/technique that I can follow? I tried the above after consulting some other links. What is the best way to do this in my scenario?

EDITS: I did some modification on my code but still not getting my desired outcome.

```
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-custom">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="https://www.sellcodes.com/pro_indigo" target="_blank">
                    <img src={logoMain} width="30" height="30" alt="" />
                </a>
                <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">Football Legends</Link>
                <div className="collpase nav-collapse">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li className="navbar-item">
                            <Link to="/" className="nav-link">Players</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="navbar-item">
                            <Link to="/create" className="nav-link">Create Player</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="navbar-item">
                            <Link to="/hallofFamers" className="nav-link">Hall of Fame</Link>
                        </li>
                        {localStorage.getItem('usertoken')!==null ?
                            <React.Fragment>
                                <li className="nav-item" style={{ marginLeft: 680 }}>
                                    <Link to="/profile" className="nav-link">
                                        User
                                    </Link>
                                </li>
                                <li className="nav-item" style={{ marginLeft: 12 }}>
                                    <a href="" onClick={this.logOut.bind(this)} className="nav-link">
                                        Logout
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </React.Fragment>
                            : 
                            <React.Fragment>
                                <li className="navbar-item" style={{ marginLeft: 680 }}>
                                    <Link to="/login" className="nav-link">Login</Link>
                                </li>
                                <li className="navbar-item" style={{ marginLeft: 12 }}>
                                    <Link to="/register" className="nav-link">Sign Up</Link>
                                </li>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        }
                    </ul>


                </div>
            </nav>
```

As you can see, I added a ternary expression checking the availability of the storage token and then, based on that, 2 React Fragments to show different links. I am still not getting it however. 
Upon login, it shows the same Login and SignUp links.

Can you tell me why? What's the error? What's the reason neither of the above 2 approaches worked? Can anyone spot it?

Comment: any ideas people? could you tell me, where exactly my approach went wrong? 
** pls refer to the newest modification of code I added to get the full picture